# Custom animation in UICollectionViewFlowLayout - scroll direction horizontal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am implementing a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and I would like to do something like this:

[image]

Basically, this is a simple collection view with the scroll direction set as `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`.

The active cell **A** (cell in the middle) must have a fixed size (ex: 300x300) and the other cells, in this case **B**, should be smaller (ex: 275x275).

When the scroll is performed between them, both cells should transform their size.

- A size -> B size
- B size -> A size.
- B is now in the middle

I probably need to override the `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect` and implement some kind of `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`. Am I thinking right? Anyone else did this before?

Comment: It's not an answer, but I would like to suggest [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Comment: iCarousel will be a valid alternative but I really do not want to stick to a 3rd party component. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat centerX = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x + self.collectionView.frame.size.width * 0.5;

    NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attrs in attributes) {

        CGFloat diff = ABS(attrs.center.x - centerX);

        CGFloat newScale = diff * scaleFactor / (self.itemSize.width + self.minimumLineSpacing);

        if (newScale > scaleFactor) {
            newScale = scaleFactor;
        }

        attrs.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1 - newScale, 1 - newScale);
    }

    return attributes;
}
```